# Identify this BMX bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

Please help me identify this frame and if you notice anything else that catches your eye I am debating on purchasing.

Comment: It would help a lot if you can please tell us the words written on the downtube in Blue, and any other wording on the bike.

Comment: Since it looks like the original finish, then the logos on the bike likely state the brand and model.

Answer (score 0):

I see either magnesium or plastic trispoke wheels, which were desirable for the looks and their ability to never need truing.  They may not be original to the bike.

The brakes appear to have a Potts mod, and a detangler suggesting it was for tricks.

However there's a kickstand.  I suspect it unlikely any BMX rider ever would have a kickstand on their bike.  This also may be a later addition.

Result - it is a fancy looking kid's bike, not a high-end bike.   That top-tube design is fairly distinctive - I've seen something similar on a GT bike but that's not authorative.